# One-dimensional jellium model in second quantization

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body, second-quantization

I want to repeat the classic exercise of the 3D jellium model in second quantization framework but in 1D. We know that the hamiltonian of the jellium model is made of three terms as explained in 'Quantum theory of many-particle system' by Fetter:

[image]

For example the first term in 3D is

$H_b=\frac{e^2 n^2}{2}\int \int \frac{e^{-\mu \vec{x}}}{|\vec{x}-\vec{x'}|}d^3x d^3x'=\frac{e^2 n^2}{2}\int d^3x \int \frac{e^{-\mu \vec{y}}}{\vec{y}} d^3y=\frac{e^2 n^2}{2}V \cdot 4\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{y^2e^{-\mu y}}{y} d^3y=$(integrate by parts)=$\frac{4\pi e^2N^2}{2V\mu^2}$

The same procedure applies also for $H_{el-b}$.
However I'm not able to compute these integrals in one dimension: if I suppose that the sistem is a straight line of lenght $L$ and $n(x)=n=\frac{N}{L}$ is constant I have

$H_b=\frac{e^2 n^2}{2}\int \int \frac{1}{|x-x'|}dx dx'=\frac{e^2 n^2}{2}\int dx' \int_0^L \frac{1}{y}dy$

which diverges when integrated in $[0;L]$. Here I didn't include the same exponential convergence factor because the result of $\int \frac{e^{-\mu y}}{y}dy$ is the exponential integral which is too strange for the problem. So my question is: how can i compute these integrals and obtain the total Hamiltonian $H$ of the system in one dimension?

Comment: Don't use images for text and Math. Use the quote function and MathJax instead.

Comment: Are you assuming 3D space when doing 1D jellium model or are you thinking of 1D space too? Like, do you need to convert to the 1D version of the Coulomb potential or are you using the 3D version?

Comment: I want to do a model of electrons in carbon nanotubes, where a nanotube can be approximated as an ideal 1D metal wire. My professor said that I should replace 3D integrals with 1D integrals, so I think the space is 1D